# JQuery Accordion Widget Dropdown Icon Incorrect Position

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've implemented a simple JQuery accordion widget according to http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#custom-icons

For some reason, the dropdown icon (ui-icon) is positioned within my section title text: [image: accordion-widget]

Has anyone else experienced this?

**html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Default functionality</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            Mauris mauris ante...shortened.
        </p>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 2</h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            Sed non urna...shortened.
        </p>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 3</h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            Nam enim risus...(shortened).
        </p>
        <ul>
            <li>List item one</li>
            <li>List item two</li>
            <li>List item three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 4</h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            Cras dictum....(shortened).
        </p>
        <p>
            Suspendisse eu nisl...(shortened).
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>​
```

**css:**

```
body {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Helvetica", "Arial",  "Verdana", "sans-serif";
    font-size: 62.5%;
}​
```

**javascript:**

```
$("#accordion").accordion();​
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! I was using version 1.8.2 for jquery-ui.css, jquery-1.8.2.js, and jquery-ui.js. I'm assuming there was some sort of conflict.

Once I changed to the following versions, the dropdown icons appeared correctly...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```